# Flutter release build build fails with exception, Missing canonical name for Reference to Criteria exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Flutter runs successfully on Android and iOS simulators, even on devices.
But when I run flutter build appbundle --release -t lib/main.dart -v  it fails with the following exception:

'Invalid argument(s): Missing canonical name for Reference to Criteria'

[image]